# Perl form and japanese characters

Tags: perl, character-encoding, forms

hello my problem is that with the japanese characters I send through a form i get something like this: %83O%83%8B%81%5B%83v%83J%83%8C%83%93%83_%81%5B

why? which encoding is?

no ide...

Comment: On what machine, which OS, which programing language, where is the data being displayed etc. etc.?

Comment: Allways Unix and perl, anyway I finally solved it, i just added so in the cgi i was calling from the form: $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

Answer (score 0):

That looks like percent-escaped [Shift-JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) text.